# Why is this limit equal to 6?

Tags: calculus, limits

Could someone please help me to solve this limit. I have tried in Wolfram Alpha and it gave me the answer of 6.

But could someone please give me a step by step derivation please?

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+ }{\frac{x^2}{\ln\Bigl[\int_0^{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}{e^\frac{t^2}{2}dt}+1-x^{\frac{2}{3}}\Bigr]}}$$

Thanks

Comment: I’m not sure I’ve worked with any integrals where the variable was being integrated over and also one of the limits of integration...

Comment: @abiessu That doesn't matter.  Replace the the one under the integral sign by $t$ if you like (and change $dx$ to $dt$ of course.)

Comment: Does LH'opital go anywhere?

Comment: Please add your attempts. Such limit equals $6$ by elementary manipulations of Landau symbols. $e^{t^2/2}=1+t^2/2+o(t^3)$ in a neighbourhood of the origin, so the integral over $(0,x^{2/3})$ is $x^{2/3}+x^2/6+o(x^2)$ and the logarithm is $x^2/6+o(x^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to start by *simplifying* the expression. Letting $x^{2/3}=u$, we get

$${x^2\over\ln\left(\int_0^{x^{2/3}}e^{t^2/2}dt+1-x^{2/3} \right)}={u^3\over\ln\left(\int_0^ue^{t^2/2}dt+1-u \right)}$$

with $u\to0^+$ as the limit.  L'Hopital is now relatively straightforward:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{u\to0^+}{u^3\over\ln\left(\int_0^ue^{t^2/2}dt+1-u \right)}
&=\lim_{u\to0^+}\left({3u^2\over e^{u^2/2}-1}\left(\int_0^ue^{t^2/2}dt+1-u \right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{u\to0^+}{3u^2\over e^{u^2/2}-1}\quad(\text{since }\int_0^0e^{t^2/2}dt+1-0=0+1-0=1)\\
&=\lim_{v\to0^+}{6v\over e^v-1}\quad(\text{letting }v=u^2/2)\\
&=6\quad\text{(by L'Hopital again, if you like)}
\end{align}$$

The real take-home lesson here is that since $x$ is a variable being taken to $0$, there is really no need to have fractional powers of it in the expression. A simple rewriting can make life ever so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}{e^\frac{t^2}{2}dt}=\int_0^{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}
{[1+\frac{t^2}{2}+o(t^2)]dt}=x^{2/3}+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)\\
\Rightarrow \ln[{\int_0^{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}{e^\frac{t^2}{2}dt}+1-x^{\frac{2}{3}}}]=
\ln[1+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)]=\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)\\
\Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{\ln[{\int_0^{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}{e^\frac{t^2}{2}dt}+1-x^{\frac{2}{3}}}]}=\frac{x^2}{\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)}=6.
$$